# render Raster Layer from pyQgis 3

Tags: raster, pyqgis

i'm using pyQGis 3 with PyQt5 and i'm trying to render a registred Raster Layer into a file PNG using Python script. The problem is that in the new API they removed QgsMapRender and replaced it with QgsMapSettings and QgsMapRenderJob so i don't know how to render my Raster Layer using command line. in the GUI i just use save map as image and the map will be rendered. How can i do it with command line.
here is where i'm stucked.

```
# create image
img = QImage(QSize(800, 600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

# set image's background color
color = QColor(255, 255, 255)
img.fill(color.rgb())

# create painter
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

render = QgsMapRenderer() #Im stucked Here
#i changed it with 
render=QgsMapSettings() 


# set layer set
 render.setLayers(layer) #here i have a QgsRasterLayer
render.setLayerSet(layer) 

# set extent
rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.1)
render.setExtent(rect)

# set output size
render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())

# do the rendering
render.render(p)

p.end()

# save image
img.save("render.png","png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob` together with `QgsMapSettings`. `QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob` takes the `QgsMapSettings` and `QPainter` as parameters and replaces the `QgsMapRender` that was used previously. You would use `QgsMapSettings` for the composition details and `QPainter` for the image creation details.

I have not tested this actual code, but it should be close to correct from your test sample:

```
# create image
img = QImage(QSize(800, 600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

# set image's background color
color = QColor(255, 255, 255)
img.fill(color.rgb())

# create painter
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

mapSettings = QgsMapSettings() # first create the map settings, then pass to a renderer

# set layer set
mapSettings.setLayers([layer]) # this takes a list of QgsMapLayer as input

# set extent
rect = QgsRectangle(mapSettings.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.1)
mapSettings.setExtent(rect)

# set output size
mapSettings.setOutputSize(img.size()) # dpi is now set separately (you would use mapsettings.setDpi(), but it's not necessary here)

# do the rendering
render = QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob(mapSettings, p) # takes the settings and painter as parameters
render.start()             # rendering is now asynchronous, so you could use threads here
render.waitForFinished()   # but we will block until it's finished
p.end()

# save image
img.save("render.png","png")
```